# Java Applets broken on different IE versions 8+ but was working a while ago?

Tags: java, google-chrome, internet-explorer, applet

We have a signed applet that was working for a long period of time, but last week some of our clients using IE 8 + 9 started to complain that the functions exposed by our applet aren't working anymore which we verified on-spot and on our testing machines. We are a bit confused as each time we come up with a possible root-cause, we go and test it on the client machine and it it turns to be not the one.

Has anyone observed that Applets stopped to work lately on IE8+ in the last couple of weeks due to one of the following reasons:

1. A Microsoft update.
2. A Java update. (The current one we are using is
       Java8u45)

   Many thanks in advance :)

   *** Update: Some users reported the issue on Chrome now too and there are no signs that the page is loading the applet at all.

Comment: Can you test it in firefox/chrome? Is it working there?

Comment: @Lonzak, yep it works on both FF and Chrome :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended-up creating a stand-alone Java application that the browser talks to using XHR calls with CORS enabled. This way we came to a state where the printing logic is always loaded and ready to respond to requests coming from pages. Also, bringing out the applet from running as a browser extension/plugin to a stand-alone application means there no need to initialise the applet on each reload which yields better performance and user experience.

Thanks everyone for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Its Mainly the security issue by Java 8, Which is not allowing now to display or load the self signed Applets on browser. Please open **configure java** in settings and in security TAB put the **URL** of the html page which is using applet in **Exception Site List**

This should work for for. :)[image]

Comment: Thanks George for your reply. Here's the catch, when I open the page on IE, I get no dialogs that indicate my application was blocked :|

 It's as if IE is ignoring the applet and the JRE/Java Plugin are not invoked.

 I will give it a try anyway :)

Comment: I tried this one and it didn't work. The issue we are facing here is not a typical liveconnect/applet blocking thing. I guess it's an issue that was introduced with the latest Java update, namely 8u45.